# How much of my money does my Mum spend when she buys me things?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

In *Pokemon Gold*, *Silver* and *Crystal* (and the remakes, *Heart Gold* and *Soul Silver*), your Mum can take a percentage of your winnings per battle for 'safekeeping'.

Unfortunately, she's a spend-thrift, and is constantly ringing me about how she "Found [another] useful item whilst shopping!", which she bought using ***my hard-earned cash***.

What I would like to know is, *how much money is she spending on these items?*

- Is it a flat fee regardless of item?
- If not, is it discounted? or does she pay full price for what is probably the 50th Paralyze Heal she's bought?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, you mother loves you and is only doing you a favor by buying you helpful items.  It's not her fault she cares.  She only wants what's best for you and your pokemon.

[In the original games](http://www.serebii.net/gs/savings.shtml), your kind, loving mother buys items from a set list **based on how much money she has saved**.

- Repel         **200**
- Super Potion      **600**
- Repel         **900**
- Charmander Doll   **1800**
- Moonstone     **3000**
- Clefairy Doll     **4800**
- Pikachu Doll      **8000**
- Big Snorlax       **22700**

[In the remakes](http://www.serebii.net/heartgoldsoulsilver/savings.shtml), your sweet, gentle mother will buy you an item for **every 10,000** you save.  [Some of these are one time items and some of these are repeatable](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mom#Items_purchased).

**One Time**

- Repel
- Silk Scarf
- Super Potion
- Moon Stone
- Hyper Potion
- Choice Scarf
- Muscle Band
- Focus Sash

**Multiple Times**

- Passho Berry
- Wacan Berry
- Rindo Berry
- Yache Berry
- Chople Berry
- Kebia Berry
- Shuca Berry
- Coba Berry
- Payapa Berry
- Tanga Berry
- Charti Berry
- Kasib Berry
- Haban Berry
- Colbur Berry
- Babiri Berry
- Chilan Berry

> To collect the items she purchases, just go to any PokéMart and meet up with the delivery man in red. He will give you these items. He can only handle five items at any one time so once he reaches five items, if you have not collected them, then your mother will stop spending your money.

Comment: Uhm. If the delivery man is full and you have earned 50,000 dollars after the point that he became full (so if you didn't let him fill up he would've had 10 separate items for you) will youre mother buy 5 more items immediately after emptying him or does the count only start when an open slot appears.

Comment: I would guess that your mom will only one purchase item the moment a multiple of 10,000 is reached _and_ there is room.

Comment: @Reafexus - to add to Origami's comment, she only rings directly after you've sent her money (i.e. at the end of a battle) so she won't ring directly after I pick up the current deliveryman items anyaway